# How correctly install ssl certificate using certbot in docker?

Tags: node.js, docker, ssl, nginx, certbot

I am trying to deploy `Node.js/Express` application with `Docker`, using Let's Encrypt SSL certificates for HTTPS.

When I run `docker-compose up` command all 3 services started but I notice such warning:

```
Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
No certs found.
```

This warning happens when docker tried to execute `RUN /scripts/certbot-auto -n certificates` command in `certbot/Dockerfile` file.

Inside `/var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log` file I see this:

```
2019-08-21 10:27:50,354:DEBUG:certbot.main:certbot version: 0.37.1
2019-08-21 10:27:50,355:DEBUG:certbot.main:Arguments: ['-n']
2019-08-21 10:27:50,355:DEBUG:certbot.main:Discovered plugins: PluginsRegistry(PluginEntryPoint#apache,PluginEntryPoint#manual,PluginEntryPoint#nginx,Plugin$
2019-08-21 10:27:50,372:DEBUG:certbot.log:Root logging level set at 20
2019-08-21 10:27:50,372:INFO:certbot.log:Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
```

Also in the logs of nginx container I notice such warning:

```
2019/08/21 10:28:37 [emerg] 1#1: cannot load certificate "/etc/letsencrypt/live/tols/fullchain.pem": BIO_new_file() failed (SSL: error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:fopen('/etc/letsencrypt/live/tols/fullchain.pem','r') error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file)
```

**QUESTION**: As far as I understand, ssl certificate was not created. How fix this problem and correctly install certificate using certbot?

**Structure**:

```
certbot/
    certbot-auto
    Dockerfile
    register
nginx/
    Dockerfile
    nginx.conf
server/
    bin/
        www.js
Dockerfile
docker-compose.yml
```

**docker-compose.yml**:

```
version: '3'

services:
  frontend:
    build: ./
    image: tols_frontend_image
    container_name: tols_frontend_container
    restart: always
    volumes:
    - certbot-webroot-tols:/tols-frontend/public/.well-known
    - certbot-letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt

  certbot:
    build: ./certbot
    image: tols_certbot_image
    container_name: tols_certbot_container
    restart: always
    volumes:
    - certbot-webroot-tols:/webroots/tols/.well-known
    - certbot-letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt

  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    image: tols_nginx_image
    container_name: tols_nginx_container
    ports:
    - "9012:80"
    - "9013:443"
    restart: always
    volumes:
    - certbot-webroot-tols:/webroots/tols/.well-known
    - certbot-letsencrypt:/tols/letsencrypt

volumes:
  certbot-webroot-tols:
  certbot-letsencrypt:
```

**certbot/Dockerfile:**

```
FROM debian:jessie

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y cron bash wget
RUN mkdir -p /webroots/tols/.well-known /scripts

WORKDIR /scripts
COPY certbot-auto certbot-auto
RUN chmod a+x ./certbot-auto
RUN /scripts/certbot-auto -n certificates
COPY register /scripts/
RUN chmod +x /scripts/register

VOLUME /webroots
VOLUME /etc/letsencrypt
RUN echo "0 0 1 * * root /scripts/certbot-auto renew" >/etc/cron.d/certbot

CMD [ "cron", "-f" ]
```

**certbot/register**:

```
#!/bin/sh
/scripts/certbot-auto certonly --webroot -w /webroots/$1 -d $1
```

**nginx/Dockerfile**:

```
FROM nginx
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443
```

**nginx/nginx.conf**:

```
user  root;
worker_processes  1;
error_log  /var/log/nginx-error.log debug;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}
http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
    access_log  /var/log/nginx-access.log  main;
    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
    server {
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
        server_name tols;
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/tols/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/tols/privkey.pem;
        location / {
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
            proxy_pass http://frontend:3010/;
            proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
            proxy_redirect off;
        }
        location /.well-known {
            root /webroots/tols/.well-known;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Nurzhan, where is the _fullchain.pem_ file in your structure? In any of your script's beside nginx you are mentioning it, if your certbot service DEPENDS on nginx, you may use **depends_on** in your yml

Answer (score 2):

Just deploy docker container with this command to install letencrypt ssl certificates

```
docker run \
--name=letsencrypt \
--cap-add=NET_ADMIN \
-e PUID=1000 \
-e PGID=1000 \
-e TZ=Europe/London \
-e URL=your.domain.com \
-e VALIDATION=http \
-e EMAIL=****@gmail.com \
-e PROD=true \
-p 443:443 \
-p 80:80 \
-v /path/to/appdata/config:/config \
-d \
--restart unless-stopped \
linuxserver/letsencrypt
```

Now auto renew certificates with the script available in /app/le-renew.sh
Install crontab to do this

```
0 0 1 * * sudo docker exec letsencrypt /app/le-renew.sh
```

Comment: Note that the docker image "linuxserver/letsencrypt" has been renamed to [linuxserver/swag](https://hub.docker.com/r/linuxserver/swag).

Answer (score 0):

SSL certificates generated by Let's Encrypt are valid for 90 days and then renew automatically

Here is the docker implementation of Letsencrypt from `docker-compose.yml`

**letsencrypt:**

```
image: jrcs/letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion:v1.7
container_name: letsencrypt
restart: always
volumes_from:
    - nginx
volumes:
  - ./letsencrypt/certs:/etc/nginx/certs:rw
  - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
environment:
  - REUSE_PRIVATE_KEYS=true
```

---

For nginx here is the code from `docker-compose.yml`

**nginx:**

```
image: jwilder/nginx-proxy:0.6.0
container_name: nginx
restart: always
labels:
  - com.github.jrcs.letsencrypt_nginx_proxy_companion.nginx_proxy
ports:
  - "443:443"
  - "80:80"
volumes:
  - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
  - ./nginx/html:/usr/share/nginx/html
  - ./nginx/vhost.d:/etc/nginx/vhost.d
  - ./letsencrypt/certs:/etc/nginx/certs:ro
```

---

Now the question is How do I renew my Letsencrypt certification?

**To renew a certificate**

- Check the certificate common name matches the one you want to renew.
- Check the certificate details are accurate.
- Enable auto-renewal, if you want it to be auto-renewed before expiration.
- Submit the order.

Here is the command the will renew the certificate automatically

```
sudo docker exec letsencrypt /app/force_renew
```